# How to replace a pattern (return to line not preceded by dot) in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I want to replace all the return to line that is not preceded by a dot in MS word
I can do a replace of `^p` by space but I want to replace only `^p` preceded by a dot (**.**)

Comment: Not sure Word supports lookbehind but have a try with `(?<=\.)^p`

Comment: @Toto - I don't believe Word supports regular expressions in search/replace.

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking. I am reading your question as you do not want any paragraph marks in a Word document that are not preceded by a full stop (period). Is that correct. @JeffZeitlin Word does support Wild Card replaces. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm | https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/using_wildcards.html | https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=1434103986/balancecheckbookA/

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - There is a difference between wildcarding and regular expressions. The "lookbehind" that Toto suggested is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Find and Replace window.
2. In the `Find what` box, type `[!.]^13`.
3. In the `Replace with` box, type the replacement string.
4. Click More, select `Use wildcards`.

[image: MS Word wildcard search example]